# Increase one weight and redistribute other weights to add up to 1

Tags: probability, distributions, weights, weighted-mean

I have a vector of weights that sum up to 1. For example:

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2]
```

I want to force the first of these weights to be always at least equal to `0.2`, and I need to redistribute the other probabilities so that the vector still adds up to 1.

I also want this redistribution to happen proportionally to the weight: `0.4`, for example, should be affected more than `0,3`.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: "Happen proportionally to," when stated mathematically, means that if you name the weights $w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_n$ in order, there exists a constant of proportionality $\lambda$ for which when $i\gt 1,$ $w^\prime_i=\lambda w_i.$   Since both the old and new weights must sum to unity, you also are telling us that $$1=\sum_{i=1}^nw^\prime_i = \max(0.2,w_1) + \lambda\sum_{i=2}^n w_i=\max(0.2,w_1) + \lambda(1-w_1).$$ What I wonder is whether there is anything worth adding, then: your question is answered by solving this equation for $\lambda.$

Comment: Thank you @whuber, this is what I was looking for. I imagine it's quite a well-known procedure, but I lack this background. Do you have some reference I could read?

Comment: I invoked only one axiom of probability and one rule of arithmetic (which needs no reference), so for references you might consult introductory texts on probability and algebra.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll gladly accept it. If you want you can even add the steps to solve the equation and this would make it even better.